# Running some test automation before code checkin

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, perforce

I am maintaining the source control for my organization and I want to run some automated tests on every checkin before it reaches the central store. Which means that when users submit their changes, I will build all the code and start the test suites.

What do I need to setup for this - assuming I have perforce as my source control?

This should be a very common problem but I probably not have the right vocabulary.

Comment: As stated your question is too broad or even not a question at all.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Sorry, i forgot to add the question. edited now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using Perforce from your tags.  There are a couple of ways you could do this:

1. Using [branches](http://kb.perforce.com/?article=4) - have the developers check into a "test" branch and make Jenkins monitor that branch for changes to build your code and run tests.  You can then integrate the test code into a separate "main" branch for everyone else to pull from.
2. If you have a recent version of Perforce, you can use the [shelving](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/shelve.html) feature. Have the developers create shelved changelists and get Jenkins to unshelve the changes to build and run the tests.  If the tests pass, the changelist can be submitted to the central depot.

We use option 2 at my work, so I can give you more details if needed - just post a comment back here.

Comment: Thanks gareth. We actually use perforce as the central repository for the company. But my team wants to go through an automation run before we checkin to perforce. I don't have control of the central server; but I will be controlling this intermediate setup. I am thinking about git, as I read that branches are cheaper in git. I have used jenkins to monitor branches, but if the branch is created dynamically - as a result of a checkin submission -; can i dynamically create a build in jenkins for this branch? any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you will have to do some custom tooling whatever you do - Git could be a good option, but you'll have to figure out how to get the changes from Git to Perforce once they're blessed.  You could also look at the new P4 Sandbox feature, which replicates a lot of Git's features in Perforce (I haven't used this so can't offer much advice)